# Spring Boot 3 and Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, gateway

I want to just add to my Spring Cloud Gateway authorization with Keycloak.
I am using Spring Boot 3 version.
Is that good idea to create a custom controller like "/auth/login", so that when request is send my service POST username and password from request "https://keycloak.some.project.com/auth/realms/aifc-portal/protocol/openid-connect/token" with RestTemplate and get token?
Also related, if I do "/auth/signup" and send request parameters with POST to keycloak with RestTemplate?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title has nothing in it that isn't already in the tags except for the version number. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user scrolling through search results will know what it contains. The title you have now says nothing at all. For tips on writing a good title, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> Is that good idea to create a custom controller like "/auth/login", so that when request is send my service POST username and password from request

No. Your application should not collect users credentials, this not how OAuth2 works. Your authorization server should already have all that is needed for registration and login.

If your frontend is rendered on the server (Thymeleaf, JSF, ...) then configure it as a "confidential" OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` and keep the gateway transparent to OAuth2 (nothing about security on it).

If your frontend is a SPA (Angular, React, Vue, ...), then consider applying the BFF pattern with the Gateway configured as "confidential" client with `oauth2Login` and also with the `TokenRelay` filter. I wrote [a tutorial for this on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

Comment: Ok, thank you!
I have then another question, how I can create user using gateway service?
Like I should POST to gatewayserver:8070/create/user with some json body, then this service should create user in Keycloak.
And also, how i can get Keycloak users list, with endpoint gatewayserver:8070/get/users?

Comment: To create user, use Keycloak user registration feature. To query users, use Keycloak's admin REST API. I do it in [this project](https://quiz.c4-soft.com/ui/). sources [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/quiz)